# Popup on bootstrap glyph icon click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I followed the tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

but want to do it with glyph icon so :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Doesn't work ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

You could make it like my code under and then 'click' on glyph should open modal. There is problem with your code becouse you cant add 'class' two times to one element.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

Put a call to action (ie. href, button) round your span tags and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the glyphicon on a button :

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: the change is here - `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>`